# limit of composite function underlying principles and special cases

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm currently learning how to find the limit of a composite function on Khan academy. In one of the question's answer section, there is an explanation on how finding limit of composite functions work

[image]

My first question is what if function u is not continuous at point L?

And also I was just wondering, is

$$lim_{x \to c} u(v(x))$$

the same as

$$ u(lim_{x \to c}v(x))$$

the same as

$$ lim_{x \to c} v(x) = L$$ $$lim_{x \to L} u(x)$$

Comment: Instead you should remember the following rule: if $u(x) \to L$ as $x\to b$ and $v(x) \to b$ as $x\to c$ and $v(x) \neq b$ as $x\to c$ then $u(v(x)) \to L$ as $x\to c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of continuity of $u$ is necessary as the following shows:

Define $ v(x)=x^2 $ for $ x\neq 0$, and $u(x)=1$ if $ x>0$, $u(x)=0$ if $ x\leq 0$.
As you observe $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}u\circ v(x)=1$ while $ u(\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}v(x))=0 $.

A condition for the equality
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow c}u\circ v(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow L}u(x)$ when $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow c}v(x)=L$ (and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow L}u(x)$ exists) is that either $ u $ is continuous at $L$ or there is a $ \delta >0$ s.t. $ \forall x(0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow v(x)\neq L) $.